# Issue loading SubKernels`RemoteKernels` package for remote kernels in Mathematica

Tags: parallelization, remote-access, high-performance-clusters

I am encountering a problem when trying to load the `` SubKernels`RemoteKernels `` package in Mathematica. The purpose of loading this package is to set up remote kernels for parallel computation on a cluster across different nodes.

However, when I execute the `` Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"] `` command, I receive the following error messages:

```
Get::noopen: Cannot open SubKernels`RemoteKernels`.
Needs::nocont: Context SubKernels`RemoteKernels` was not created when Needs was evaluated.
```

The platform is a cluster managed by slurm, and the mathematica version is 13.2.1.

Is there anything specific I need to do in order to successfully load the `SubKernels`RemoteKernels`` package? Are there any additional dependencies or steps that might be causing this issue? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 13.1, the `` SubKernels` `` package is obsolete. You would either have to use an earlier version, or adapt your code to work with the new way of launching remote kernels. This is described in detail in a tutorial [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ParallelKernelConfiguration.html), which contains a section on setting up remote kernels over ssh.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm on a cluster managed by Slurm, and I want to run Mathematica on multiple nodes. From the tutorial you mentioned, do I need to create a WSTPServer? This seems super complicated.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Slurm, I have only used Mathematica on a PBS managed cluster. The way I setup up computations there was that my main Mathematica script reads in the list of nodes that are assigned to my job, and manually launches kernels on these nodes through ssh (which is fairly simple, particularly with the revised method described in the tutorial). I forked  @Szabolc CRC` package, which unfortunately does not seem to be hosted publicly anymore.

Comment: I'm familiar with managing tasks when I have SSH access to the nodes, but in this case, I don't seem to have the necessary permissions. The only way I can submit jobs on this cluster is through sbatch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.